# AS3 image loading content is always null

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, image-loading

I have a problem with my assets loader I've created for my flash app. In a function I try to load an external image and return it from this function. My problem is that I always get loader.content set to null. This how my code looks like:

```
    public static function loadImage(path:String):BitmapData
    {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, check);
        if (path == "")
            loader.load(new URLRequest("images/default.png"));
        else
            loader.load(new URLRequest("images/" + path));
        var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap((loader.content as BitmapData));
        return image.bitmapData;
    }

    public static function check(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("Loading completed");
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, check);
    }
```

Any ideas???? I've also included my event listener which does launch.

I'm pretty sure it's because the loader works asynchronously, but I have no idea how to modify it to be able to return the image from the function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure it's because the loader works asynchronously

Correct

> but I have no idea how to modify it to be able to return the image from the function

There is no way to do that.

> Why?

Because it is asynchronous.

You can't return a result of a request straight after the request has been made.

The execution of the code does not pause and wait for the response to come back, so your function will hit the return statement before you get the data, and that is why it is returning `null`.

The only way to handle this is to listen for the response (Event.COMPLETE) and run a callback function after the response from the server has been received.

So following your code example, you could do:

```
private static var _callback :Function;

public static function loadImage(path:String, callback:Function):void
{
     _callback = callback;
     // ....
```

and then:

```
 public static function check(e:Event):void
 {
     // ...
     _callback( whateverYouWantToReturnGoesHere );
```

This should work assuming that you only have one image loaded at a time (as your methods are static), otherwise you will need to implement some sort of request queue handling.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your explanation is 100% but your code sample has a minor flaw - `loadImage` can't return anything :-)

Comment: @Marty thank you for the edit and comment. Sorry for that :) I haven't touched as3 since Dec 2012, just trying my best to not forget everything, please feel free to edit this answer if you wouldn't mind :)

Comment: I guess this is a good start. I was wondering how to make loadImage return the data I want and I think the only method is to stop execution of the function until the data is loaded. It's not the perfect solution, but I can't find anything better that would suit my needs. Do You think it's something acceptable? (I'd then put while loop checking whether content is something different than null?)

Comment: and if it's any difference it does not necessarily need to be static.

Comment: but why do you want to have it returned from the loadImage function, just start loading and wait until it is fully downloaded and then make use of it.

Comment: well, because I have different classes using this loader. Objects of these classes are initialized with a path - then I need to get the image based on that path. Would You then recommend implementing loading functions for each class? I need to somehow suspend loading of my app until images are loaded. So maybe I should preload my images (and sounds) on app initialization and then just create my Bitmaps based on preloaded data?

Comment: well create "manager" classes for the assets loader from which other classes will request the asset. Manager will load the asset and notify other classes that asset is ready (if already loaded then it will notify immediately). Other classes will need to register to the event of that manager to be able to respond to "asset ready" event, and at that point will be able to access it.

Comment: hmm, would You please present me with an example of that solution?

Comment: then ask another question

Answer (score 0):

Your getting a 'null' because you're referring to `loader.content` too soon. Here's a simplified version that works, just fine,  in a timeline:

```
 var loader:Loader = new Loader();
 loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, check);

 loader.load(new URLRequest("images/default.png"));



function check(e:Event):void
{
    var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(195,130,false,0xFFFFFFFF)
    var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
    bmd.draw(loader.content);
    trace(loader.content);
    trace("Loading completed");
    addChild(image);
    e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, check);
}
```

You can put it back into a form suitable for your classes.

Comment: like I said, I MUST return BitmapData from inside my function, because it is used globally across my whole application. This solves literally nothing for me.

Comment: You certainly DIDN'T say 'from "inside" the function' in your question. You'd get a better answer if you asked a better question!  Make the BitmapData instance a static variable and you can access it globally.

Comment: "but I have no idea how to modify it to be able to return the image from the function.".

Comment: Well, we've solved the 'null' problem. What exactly to you want to 'modify?' Can you explain, clearly, where or how do you want to use the image?

Comment: Alright, this is a function from a class `AssetsLoader`. It is a class, that I use functions of to load all images (and sound files by the way) used in my app. So what I do, inside a different class:
`var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(AssetsLoader.loadImage(path));` which should result in loading an image from an external source, returning a `BitmapData` and create a new bitmap based on that data inside other classes. Therefore in a function `loadImage` I have to load it using a loader and return `BitmapData` that has been loaded - from inside that function.

Comment: Why do you want to return a BitmapData anyway? Why not just a Bitmap?

Comment: well, because I have the construction shown above (`var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(AssetsLoader.loadImage(path));`), so it should return a BitmapData, which is a parameter for Bitmap constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should say:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData;
```

and

```
var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap(event.target.content.bitmapData)
```

instead of

```
var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap((loader.content as BitmapData));
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I can see any way it will help me. Won't solve my problem at all.